# Why Go Limiter isn't working when limit = 0?

Tags: go, rate

I'm using [Go Limiter](http://golang.org/x/time/rate) and seems not working properly when Limit is 0.
It's supposed to reject all events, but it doesn't. (Note that I'm not using rate.Every(), with set limit Inf in case of 0)

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
)

func main() {
    rl := rate.NewLimiter(0, 1)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        fmt.Println(rl.Allow())
    }

}
```

The results is all true.

You can check on [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bm0HPdn8aDo)

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.Burst `Burst is the maximum number of tokens that can be consumed in a single call to Allow, Reserve, or Wait, so higher Burst values allow more events to happen at once. A zero Burst allows no events, unless limit == Inf.`

Comment: @mh-cbon the problem isn't the burst value, is the limit value (the first one). If limit = 0, no events should be allowed.

Comment: fill a bug report if you think you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my reply for this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18763#issuecomment-1214742071

> And this has been fixed in x/time/rate package: https://github.com/golang/time/blob/e5dcc9cfc0b9553953e355dde5bdf4ff9f82f742/rate/rate.go#L405
>
> Use the latest version could solve this issue, for example:
>
> golang.org/x/time v0.0.0-20220722155302-e5dcc9cfc0b9
>
> Or here's a workaround for this issue:
>
> ```
> limiter := NewLimiter(math.SmallestNonzeroFloat64, 1)
> ```